Discontinuous function on R that can be uniformly approximated by polynomials
This is my first question here, I have read from here that any almost everywhere continuous function that is almost everywhere equal to a continuous function, can be uniformly approximated by polynomials, but I cannot find any example. Let's say, if we define $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if $x=0$} \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$ Given $\varepsilon>0$, how do I find a polynomial $p_\varepsilon$ such that $\lVert f-p_\varepsilon\rVert_\infty<\varepsilon$ on $[0,1]$?
I am still studying Elementary Real Analysis and have yet exposed to Stone-Weierstrass, I only know Weierstrass Approximation and Bernstein Polynomials. My teacher said if we can uniformly approximate a function on a compact set by polynomials then it must also be uniformly continuous too. I don't think it is true, because wouldn't it automatically make the function continuous? But I cannot find a concrete counter-example anywhere even after searching up the forum.

The uniform limit of a sequence of continuous functions is continuous.  Your function is not continuous.  From this, you conclude...?

I am wondering if this is correct. Fix some small $\varepsilon>0$, then we must have a point $x$ very close to 0, that $f(x)=0$ but $p_\varepsilon(x)$ must be quite close to 1. So we cannot approximate the polynomial, but doesn't it contradict the result I read earlier?

From this, I can conclude $f$ is indeed not the uniform limit of a sequence of polynomials. But doesn't this imply, if a function can be uniformly approximated by a sequence of polynomials, then the function is continuous?

A uniform limit of polynomials must be continuous, since every polynomial is continuous, and a uniform limit of continuous functions is continuous. Therefore, you cannot find a discontinuous function that can be uniformly approximated by continuous functions (or polynomials, in particular).

I agree with you now, so the converse of Weierstrass approximation, is also true? But then I am curious what was happening in the Reddit post I linked?

@PneuJai Every continuous function can be uniformly approximated by polynomials, and any function that can be uniformly approximated by polynomials must be continuous. I cannot access the post you've linked but feel free to edit your question to include anything else you wish to ask.

The post is as follows:
Approximating by polynomials
I have recently learned about stone-weierstrass proof that you can approximate any almost everywhere continuous function on [0,1] by polynomials.
I was wondering if one can find the error term in the approximation? I suppose the error term depends on the continuity of the function. I have tried to find articles on this but haven't found any.
